# exclude one file in 'for file in ; do ; done' command

Tags: shell, for-loop, find, sh, drone.io

since a few weeks I've been using Drone.io a CI/CD tool and found out that only bin/sh commands can be executed in it and not bin/bash. Now I'm looking for a one line command to find files on '*.yaml' except 'secrets.yaml' and run a command with the found *.yaml files.

What i have tried is:

```
find /config -maxdepth 1 -name "*.yaml" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file ; do esphome "$file" config ; done
```

while read doest work with bin/sh

This command works but cant find a way to exlude secrets.yaml

```
for file in config/*.yaml ; do esphome "$file" config ; done
```

How do I exclude secrets.yaml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there. Just use a `-not`  or `!` to exclude files that you don't want to.

```
find config -type f -name '*.yaml' -not -name 'secrets.yaml' -exec esphome '{}' config \;
```

Or

```
for file in config/*.yaml; do if [ "${file##*/}" != 'secrets.yaml' ]; then esphome "$file" config; fi; done
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I test both command the first gives me no output at all in de drone.io consol it only shows the command itself and i dont know why. This is what i see. 
`find /config -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.yaml' -not -name 'secrets.yaml' -exec esphome '{}' config \;`
the second command does work but is does not ignore the secrets.yaml file.

Comment: Make sure everything is correct. You are probably don't need `-maxdepth 1`. Is `/config` the right path? Maybe you want `config` instead. See my edited.

Comment: Yes! with just 'config' it is working. `find config -type f -name '*.yaml' -not -name 'secrets.yaml' -exec esphome '{}' config \;` Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `find`.

```
for file in config/*.yaml; do 
  case "$file" in
  config/secrets.yml) continue ;;
                   *)  esphome "$file" config ;;
  esac
done
```

or

```
for file in config/*.yaml; do 
  if [ config/secrets.yml != "$file" ]; then esphome "$file" config; fi
done
```

If it were `bash` -

```
$: touch a.yaml b.yaml c.yaml secrets.yaml
$: shopt -s extglob
$: echo !(secrets).yaml
a.yaml b.yaml c.yaml
```

so -

```
shopt -s extglob
for file in config/!(secrets).yaml; do esphome "$file" config ; done
```

Comment: Except OP is limited to sh, and that's bash specific.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your own drone instance, you might be interested in a [conversion extension](https://docs.drone.io/extensions/conversion/) that we wrote https://github.com/meltwater/drone-convert-pathschanged

The extension allows pipelines or pipeline steps to be included or excluded based on the files changed.

```yaml
  - name: example
    image: busybox
    commands:
    - echo "a file other than secrets.yaml was changed"
    when:
      paths:
        include:
        - '*.yaml'
        exclude:
        - secrets.yaml
```